# WebKit on 10.8: How to programmatically set the value of an input[type=file] field?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit, osx-mountain-lion, forms

**Setup**:

- Mac OS X  10.8.2
- Normal Cocoa app which links against OS-provided version of WebKit framework. Specifically, the contents of: `/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/version.plist` are:

```
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>BuildVersion</key>
        <string>5</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>8536</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>8536.26.14</string>
        <key>ProjectName</key>
        <string>WebKit</string>
        <key>SourceVersion</key>
        <string>7536026014000000</string>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

---

I have a WebKit-based Cocoa app which loads an HTML document containing a normal HTML form in a WebView. The HTML form contains a file chooser input field like this:

```
<form name="foo">
    <input type="file" name="bar">
</form>
```

I'd like to set the value of this file chooser programmatically (from Objective-C if possible, but I'll do whatever works).

As far as I can tell, this method has never worked:

```
DOMHTMLInputElement *inputEl = ... // fetch input element
[inputEl setValue:@"some/file.txt"];
```

I assume there is some security restriction/policy in WebKit which prevents this from working. I assume this is an intentional security feature in WebKit, not a bug.

---

However, in OS X 10.7 Lion, I **was** able to work around this restriction with a bit of a hack.

In Lion, you could programmatically **click** the `input` element:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark WebFrameLoadDelegate

- (void)webView:(WebView *)wv didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    if (frame != [wv mainFrame]) return;

    DOMAbstractView *win = (id)[frame windowObject];
    DOMDocument *doc = [win document];
    DOMHTMLFormElement *formEl = (id)[[doc forms] namedItem:@"foo"];
    DOMHTMLInputElement *inputEl = (id)[[formEl elements] namedItem:@"bar"];
    [inputEl click];
}
```

Which would produce a call to `-[WebUIDelegate webView:runOpenPanelForFileButtonWithResultListener:]`. Then, you could implement that delegate method to programmatically set the value of the result listener immediately:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark WebUIDelegate

- (void)webView:(WebView *)wv runOpenPanelForFileButtonWithResultListener:(id<WebOpenPanelResultListener>)listener {
    [listener chooseFilename:@"some/file.txt"];
}
```

Although this was an ugly hack, it worked perfectly. It had the desired effect of immedately setting the value of the file upload `input` element. No "open panel" would appear on screen.

---

I'm afraid WebKit has stopped allowing this in the version which shipped with 10.8. The part that has changed is:

```
[inputEl click];
```

This no longer produces a click event on the element in the WebKit shipping with 10.8.

I have tried other methods of clicking which worked on 10.7, but no longer work on 10.8:

```
DOMUIEvent *evt = (id)[doc createEvent:@"UIEvents"];
[evt initUIEvent:@"click" canBubble:YES cancelable:YES view:win detail:1];
[inputEl dispatchEvent:evt];
```

These methods worked in 10.7, but none work in 10.8.

---

**So**, Is there any way to programmatically set the value of this file chooser in 10.8?

**NOTE**: I **DO NOT** want to ship a custom version of WebKit with my app. Other than that, I'm open to any suggestion (ObjC or JS or whatever).

How can you programmatically set the value of a file chooser in WebKit which ships with 10.8?

I have an example test project (reduced test case) available for your convenience here: http://tod.nu/FileUploadTest.zip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work if you dispatch the event via the AppKit event system. Something like:

```
NSView *docView = [[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView];
NSRect docFrame = [docView frame];

NSPoint point = [el boundingBox].origin;
point.y = docFrame.size.height - point.y;

NSEvent *evt = [NSEvent mouseEventWithType:NSLeftMouseDown location:point modifierFlags:0 timestamp:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] windowNumber:[self.webView.window windowNumber] context:0 eventNumber:0 clickCount:1 pressure:0];
[self.webView.window sendEvent:evt];

evt = [NSEvent mouseEventWithType:NSLeftMouseUp location:point modifierFlags:0 timestamp:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] windowNumber:[self.webView.window windowNumber] context:0 eventNumber:0 clickCount:1 pressure:0];
[self.webView.window sendEvent:evt];
```

There's probably a better way to do the coordinate system conversion, but that's not really the important part.

Comment: I want to get you a million upvotes, but I can't. Thanks a bunch!